# How to export a Model Branch from a version controlled package

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to set up a federated model, in Sparx EA.  According to the documentation, it is reasonable:

- set a package (or model) as a branch,
- put under version control, export as .eab file.
- In other file, import branch .eab file.

However, I have no option to **Export as Model Branch** when I check the context menu of a package or model. Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?  (Version 15.2).
[image: Package Control options I see]

Comment: Your package is not version controlled, so you don't get the options associated with version controlled packages.

Answer (score 1):

The option can be found under **Package Control | Export as Model Branch** in the context menu of a **version controlled** package.

[image]

But you can also simply import the xmi file of the version controlled package. If there are nested version controlled packages you can use the option **Get Latest** to get the nested package context.

Comment: Thank you, Geert.  It is nice to see all of those options do exist.  This is what I see--Well, I don't seem to have the option to paste an image on here.  Under Package Control, I have the options: Package Baselines | Import a Model Branch; Version Control Settings.

I can go with the XMI import/version control until I can figure this out.

Comment: You might amend your question by adding the picture right there.

Comment: Thank you, qwerty, didn't think of that.  It is included now--as a hyperlink.